# How to: seaching XML child nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Given a piece of Xml Like the one below.  How would I write an XPATH Query to get the value of the 'leaf2' child where the 'key' value has a particular values (say 2)

I'm working in C# .NET.  At the moment I'm just looking at getting the Xpath for key using SelectNodes , finding the right value then navigating back up to leaf2.

```
<root>
    <child>
        <anotherChild>
           <key>1</key>
        </anotherChild>
        <leaf1>X</leaf1>
        <leaf2>Y</leaf2>
        <leaf3></leaf3>
    </child>
    <child>
        <anotherChild>
           <key>2</key>
        </anotherChild>
        <leaf1>A</leaf1>
        <leaf2>B</leaf2>
        <leaf3></leaf3>
    </child>
</root>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want:

```
/root/child[anotherChild/key = '2']/leaf2
```

This is saying, "get elements named `leaf2`, whose parent is `child` and whose grandparent is `root`, where `child` is being filtered by its child named `anotherChild` with a child named `key` whose value is `2`."

Answer (score 2):

Or, perhaps a bit more flexibly because it doesn't assume the grandfather is root

```
//child/anotherChild/key[text()="2"]/../../leaf2
```

"find the key with text 2, parent anotherChild and grandparentchild, go to grandparent(i.e. child, and find leaf2"

Comment: Should do. I tested it in SketchPath against your XML (so not actually in C#)